# Intersecting two planes in Cartesian space

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have two equations,
$$
7x=9-9z
$$ and
$$
7y=17+10z
$$
if we want to find the vector form for these in a $3D~$ Cartesian plane. How would we do that, because in the answer sheet of my book, the answer would be:

$$
 x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} 9 \\ -10 \\-7 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Which I can't figure out why it is after an hour of trying to get to it.

I got this from a question to find the plane of intersection between planes

`3x + 2y + z = -1` & `2x - y + 4z = 5`. I don't even know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I've changed the title to make it more descriptive -- feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange both equations in terms of $z$, so: $$z=\frac19(9-7x)=\frac{1}{10}(7y-17)$$ and then pick $x$ and $y$ in the form $\alpha+t\beta$ so that $z$ cancels nicely. As long as you use the $z$ from a given $x$ to find $y$, any $x$ you pick is fine, but make sure that $|\alpha|<|\beta|$ at the end by subtracting multiples to simplify.

Since $z$ in terms of $x$ cancels if $x$ is a multiple of $9$, we pick $x=9t\implies z=1-7t$ and then $$1-7t=\frac{1}{10}(7y-17)\implies y=\frac{27}{7}-10t)$$

We then compile and see that: $$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{27}{7} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} 9 \\ -10 \\-7 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is the correct answer.

Comment: You are correct, and I'm a fool for not checking. I made a sign error halfway through, and flipped the sign of what I originally got ($1+10t$) without checking it.

Comment: The $-1$ is wrong. Check it against the original equation.

Comment: Yes. If you substitute $y=-1-10t$ into $7y=17+10z$ you get $z=-(2.4+7t)$ which is not the formula given for $z$ in the answer ($1-7t$)

Comment: Sadly, textbooks are not infallible, and it is a simple slipup to make.

Comment: Not at all. The method outlined still holds true though, so you can just follow it through